# Creating a DynamicMethod to Invoke a Constructor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection.emit

I am attempting to compare various methods of invoking a constructor of a type that is unknown at compile-time.  I have four methods working: directly calling the constructor (for timing comparisons), calling ConstructorInfo.Invoke, calling Expression.Lambda.Compile, and calling Activator.Create.  The one that I am unable to get working, is using a DynamicMethod.  Here is a small sample of my code:

```
public struct Foo {
    private int _val;
    public Foo(int val) {
        _val = val;
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return _val.ToString();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var ctorInfo    = typeof(Foo).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });
    var ctorDynamic = new DynamicMethod("CreateFoo",
            typeof (Foo), new[] {typeof (int)});

    var ilGenerator = ctorDynamic.GetILGenerator();
    // Load the int input parameter onto the stack
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    // Call the constructor
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ctorInfo);
    // Return the result of calling the constructor
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    // Create a delegate for calling the constructor
    var ctorInvoker = (Func<int, Foo>)ctorDynamic.CreateDelegate(
                      typeof(Func<int, Foo>));

    // Call the constructor
    var foo = ctorInvoker(5);
}
```

When I attempt to call the constructor delegate on the final line, I get a VerificationException that says "Operation could destabilize the runtime."  I think I am missing one or more opcodes, but don't know which one(s).  Does anyone know of the proper way to do this using a DynamicMethod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to write IL, the best option is usually to write the equivalent C# code and then look at the generated IL.

So, you write a method like:

```
static Foo f(int i)
{
    return new Foo(i);
}
```

And the IL will look like:

```
ldarg.0
newobj      Foo..ctor
ret
```

This shows the two errors you made:

1. To load a method argument, use `ldarg`, `ldloc` is for local variables only.
2. You need to use `newobj` to call the constructor, constructor does not behave like a `Foo`-returning method.

If you fix these errors, your code will work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you view the MSIL?  I see that there is a tool called ildasm that ships with VS2013, but couldn't find the *.re files that it is supposed to operate on.

Comment: While newobj will work, for value types it is not normal, so you wouldn't see the above emitted by the compiler. From the docs: "Value types are not usually created using newobj. They are usually allocated either as arguments or local variables, using newarr (for zero-based, one-dimensional arrays), or as fields of objects. Once allocated, they are initialized using Initobj. However, the newobj instruction can be used to create a new instance of a value type on the stack, that can then be passed as an argument, stored in a local, and so on."

Comment: @user960115 Yeah, ildasm is one option. And it operates on normal .Net .DLLs and .EXEs.

Comment: @mikez The compiler *did* emit that `newobj`. I think it's because of the constructor: `initobj` will give you `default(T)`, but it won't call any constructor.

Comment: @svick Ok, I see in this specific case it will emit `newobj`. The compiler does not typically emit a newobj instruction to create a value type. It will typically create a local to hold the value type, load the local onto the stack, then `call` the constructor. The advice to look at the the emitted IL is very good, I was just trying to head off the obvious question of why the emitted IL would not have a `newobj` instruction (but in fact it does).